# What protocols will/are ISPs use for IPv6 deployment?

Tags: internet, ipv6, isp

Currently ISPs deal out addresses via DHCP for IPv4 dynamic (single) addresses.

What protocol will/are ISPs going to use for IPv6 when they can hand a customer an entire /64 (or /48 if they are nice) block?  DHCPv6, RA?

For ISPs that support true end-to-end IPv6 will they provide gateway devices (similar to cable modem or true DSL bridges for example) that receive border information for that specific customer?

I'm just trying to get an idea of how your common residential service customer will have to configure things in an IPv6 Internet (whenever that comes).  Will it be something customers are expected to statically configure on their home wireless router?

Today with IPv4 I do it like this:  Modem (bridge) passes public IPv4 obtained via DHCPv4 from ISP to second device (wireless router).  It in turn has its own DHCPv4 service it provides on the internal lan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ISP will usually provide RA+DHCPv6 with Prefix Delegation on the link. The RA will provide the default route, and optionally the prefix information for the link (some ISPs use unnumbered links, some use numbered links). DHCPv6-PD will provide a block of addresses (usually a /56 or a /48 for residential customers, almost always a /48 for business customers) to use on the LAN side of the home router. The home router will take a /64 per LAN.